# In matlab, how to get all edges of a polygon whose indices are labelled by integers using sets

Tags: arrays, matlab, set

To put the problem in context: I have a 3D polygon, whose vertices are all labelled by integers `1,...,N`, and I have a `n*3` matrix `faces` each of whose rows indicates one of its triangular faces. E.g.

```
faces =

     1     3     5
     2     4     6
     1     3     6
     2     4     5
     1     4     5
     2     3     6
     1     4     6
     2     3     5
```

So the first row `[1 3 5]` denotes the face formed by vertices `1 3 5` and so on. Now I want to get all the *edges* of these faces.

So I want to use the concept of a set (non-ordered, unique elements). For each row of `faces` there are three edges, corresponding to three sets, say, `{1, 3}, {1, 5}, {3, 5}` (here I'm borrowing notations from Python). And I want to create a set of all these sets for all rows. How to do it in Matlab?

In Python it seems I simply can't do a set of sets, since `set`s are unhashable. In Matlab, it seems everything is a matrix, so I may have to still use a `1x2` matrix to represent each edge, which is fine, but what I want is I **don't get duplicated edges. For example, `[1 2]` and `[2 1]` are one same edge so I have to make sure one and only one of them is retained in the final dataset**.

Comment: sorry, spoke too soon...didn't see you didn't want duplicate edges. I'll spend some more time

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis thanks for your help. It's ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way:

1. create all edges for each triangle (by brute-force)
2. sort all edges, so that they all "point" in the same direction
3. select unique ones

Something like this:

```
faces = [1     3     5
         2     4     6
         1     3     6
         2     4     5
         1     4     5
         2     3     6
         1     4     6
         2     3     5];

% Create all edges
A = [faces(:, [1 2]); faces(:, [2 3]); faces(:, [1 3])];

% First sort(), then unique()
A = unique(sort(A,2), 'rows')
```

Comment: Thanks so much. As a followup question, is there any elegant way to pick out non-repeating rows? For example, if `edges = [1 2; 1 3; 1 2; 1 4]`, is there any way to just pick out `[1 3; 1 4]` since only they appear exactly once? I tried `histc` but it seems to work only with scalars and not in this case.

Comment: @Vim hint: look at `unique`'s second output argument.

Comment: You could create all the edges with one line: `A = [faces(:, [1 2]); faces(:, [2 3]); faces(:, [1 3])];`

Comment: @gnovice ugh, my brain must have fallen asleep just then...thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The super quick and easy way is to use the [`triangulation`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/triangulation.html) class and [`edges`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/triangulation.edges.html) method to find them. Given your `faces` connectivity matrix from above and assuming your vertex data is in `vertices`:

```
TR = triangulation(faces, vertices);
edgeMatrix = edges(TR);
```

And the result:

```
edgeMatrix =

     1     3
     1     4
     1     5
     1     6
     2     3
     2     4
     2     5
     2     6
     3     5
     3     6
     4     5
     4     6
```

Answer (score 1):

First search your matrix and extract each vector.
After that you can store that in another matrix.

```
edges =

 1     3 
 3     5
 1     3
 3     4
 5     1
 1     4
 4     4
 4     3

A = unique(edges,'rows')
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you kindly explain what `M` is? The original `faces` or the extracted vectors as you stated.

Comment: Also, in your result, [1 3] appears twice and [3 4] and [4 3] are duplicates.

Comment: But thanks for your idea. I think I have an idea now.